# Сравнить популярность двух заведений или мест

Tags: php, google-maps-api, google-maps, google-places-api

Стоит задача выяснить какое из двух заведений или мест является более популярным, в идеале получить число посетителей.

Один из вариантов было воспользоваться Google Places API и его Popular times, а конкретно идет речь об [этих данных](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6263531?hl=en). Но кол-во посетителей гугл не выдает и даже популярность строит на основе посещаемости за последние несколько недель. То есть сравнить два заведения тоже не получится.

Может быть есть какие-то другие варианты или сервисы предоставляющие эти возможности?

Очень буду рад помощи.

Comment: Я думаю подобные данный доступны только по платной подписке. Но наверное есть какие-то урезанные варианты, например https://www.factual.com/products/measurement/

Comment: @VasinYuriy В Google Places API вы абсолютно правы, эти данные доступны при платной подписке. Но к сожалению они не дают того что необходимо. Очень полезная ссылка, огромное спасибо.

Comment: по моему популярность за несоклько недель наоборот хорошо, или нет? смысл популярности то в чем? популярно место сейчас или нет, а не то, было популярно оно год назад или нет.

Comment: @teran Вы не поняли. Мне нужна возможность сравнить популярность между двумя заведениями. А гугл дает свою статистику популярности основываясь на последних двух неделях конкретного заведения.

Answer (score 1):

Есть бесплатные сервисы с ограничением по количеству запросов в месяц. Например - *[Factual Measurement](https://www.factual.com/products/measurement/)*.

Документация доступна на английском языке: https://support.factual.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000584832-Factual-Measurement

Comment: Я к сожалению не могу найти возможность где бы мог сравнить популярность двух выбранных мной заведений. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете.